# How can I measure the performance of a Seam application?

Tags: performance, jsf, jboss, richfaces, seam

I have a Jboss application using Seam. The application is a user-facing web application.
One page containing a large `rich:dataTable` (800 rows, 11 columns). This page is very slow to load, taking 14 seconds of which only a negligible portion is spent downloading the page. I would prefer to keep displaying the table on one page rather than paginating it.

I would like to measure the time used by the different phases of the JSF life-cycle. The database queries fetching data for the page are fairly optimized, and I suspect that the response rendering is taking significant time, but would like to confirm this by measurement.

The application runs on Jboss 4.2.3 with Seam 2.1.0.GA and RichFaces 3.3.3.

Answer (score 4):

I would recomend JProfiler or any other profiler you think is good.

I also use firebug in Firefox to se how long the server side takes compaired to the client side.

And read this articile by Dan Allen 
http://www.jsfcentral.com/articles/speed_up_your_jsf_app_1.html

Answer (score 2):

I use an interceptor someone created awhile back.  It doesn't measure the phases, but it does measure how many times every intercepted method runs and how long it takes to run it.  You can turn it on or off with a debug switch.
Available here:
http://seamframework.org/Community/SeamPerformanceProblemRewardingWorkaround